# Can I submit an iOS app that doesn't support the 4s?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

Is it possible to submit an iOS app to the App Store that only supports the 5 and 6 versions of the iPhone and doesn't support the iPhone 4s. The 4s has a different aspect ratio than the 5 and 6 and since I need the entire screen space my app won't look good on the 4s so for now I don't want to support it. Is this possible? If so, are there specific settings that I need to change in Xcode to do this?

Comment: No you can't omit a device. That goes against Apple logic since not everyone in the world can own all the devices they sell. You should consider restructuring your layout in order to pass the review process. And don't forget. For every iPhone 4 your disregarding your pretty much saying screw you to all the iPod owners as well

Comment: Additionally with the introduction of size classes in iOS 8 you can expect more devices with different aspect ratios to come. So better take care of that now than later.

Comment: @soulshined: "No you can't omit a device" is not quite correct.  There are apps that do not support iPad1, etc.

Comment: @user523234: The apps that do not support the first generation iPad simply require iOS6 as the minimum OS since the iPad 1 only supports up to iOS 5.1.1. There is no way to omit a device directly. (From Wikipedia: "On June 11, 2012 it was announced that iOS 6 would not be released for the first generation iPad as to no explanation why, hence making iOS 5.1.1 the final official operating system version available for the device.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to support the iPhone 4S screen size.

Here's article 2.10 from the App Store Review Guidelines ( https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality ):

> **2.10** iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, **and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution**

I guess if you have to support 2X iPhone 3GS resolution for iPad, you have to do it for iPhone as well.

Comment: 2.10 says that *iPhone Apps* must support that resolution... What about *universal apps*? Is there anything from Apple explicitly saying that we have to support all the phones types? I can't find anything so far...

Comment: I don't see why Apple would allow you to not support some screen sizes unless the latest iOS doesn't. Maybe you can forget about non-Retina screens size iOS8 is only supported by iPhone 4s and above but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

This must have changed since you asked this question.  In iOS9, you can cut off devices not supporting 64 bit architecture.  See this article:

http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/10/ios-9-older-devices-lose-support-apps/

Thats great (from a developer and legacy support standpoint), especially since 4s usage is really dwindling.  Problem is, it cuts off a lot of the iPads (over 80%), since they only switched to 64 bit when the iPad Air was introduced.  So beware of what you cut off in tablet world with this approach.

I'm not sure if you can target specific devices though, which would be the most ideal.

Comment: However, if you stop supporting 64-bit, you also stop supporting iPhone 5 and 5c.

Answer (score 2):

Now, with the pending release of iOS 10, iPhone 4s support will be dropped. This means that if you make iOS 10 a requirement you won't need to support iPhone 4s. However, you'll have to wait for iOS 10 to be released (Fall 2016).

Comment: Cant wait. I dont like doing layout for iphone4 screens. Its so much easier just for 5/6/6+ since they are proportional.

Answer (score 2):

remove armv7 will remove support of 4s

[image]

Comment: This is the bese answer. But maybe you need know removing armv7 also not support iPad 1-3 and iPad mini1 ... - http://dorianroy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/iOS_Support_Matrix_v4.2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

**2017 July**

Since you're talking about aspect ratio, you still need to support the iPhone 4S resolution (640x960) because iPad running iPhone apps use the same resolution. We got two iPhone apps rejected because they were not compatible for iPad. It is mentioned in their documentation as well,

> 2.4 Hardware Compatibility
>
> 2.4.1 To ensure people get the most out of your app, iPhone apps should run on iPad whenever possible. We encourage you to consider
>   building universal apps so customers can use them on all of their
>   devices. Learn more about Universal apps.

The approval is inconsistent because one app that we submitted got approved without the support for 640x960 resolution but the next update was rejected when they found the issue. It is best that your apps support to run on iPad.